# Is it possible to stick a nail into your nose?

Tags: physiology

A friend showed me the following video a few minutes ago. He says that it's real, but I can't believe that actually. What do you think?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7z4h4Mxq_ys

The video show some guy hammering a nail into his nose.

Comment: A nail? A nail is nothing: http://youtu.be/bPzwg4yVXps   : )

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.

[Howstuffworks](http://entertainment.howstuffworks.com/arts/circus-arts/human-blockhead1.htm) has a pretty good explanation of this:

> The external portion of the nose is a little deceptive. Two nostrils
>   appear to lead almost straight up into the nasal passageway. In
>   reality, the nasal cavity, which connects the nose to the throat,
>   leads almost straight back. Its ceiling is approximately even with the
>   top of the nose, just below the eyes. Its floor tends to be almost
>   level with the alar cartilage, which forms the openings for the
>   nostrils.

[image]

As you can see in this image, there's plenty of space, but there might be some need to "wiggle" the spike in and then push up the nostrils a bit.

Comment: For the record, a while after I posted this I just had to try it for myself. Not that difficult, but very uncomfortable. Kids, [don't put stuff up your nose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Don't_stuff_beans_up_your_nose).

Answer (score 8):

It is quite likely true. It is a common circus/freak-show stunt.

The skill is called the [Human Blockhead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_Blockhead). ("Skill", not "trick", because the nail is real and does go into the head.)

[Here's a video](http://recordsetter.com/world-record/nail-fully-inserted-into-nostril/6547) of another guy inserting a 4-inch nail into his nose in a similar way.

It involves inserting the nail into the nasal cavity, and relies of people not understanding the anatomy of the skull for its impressiveness. This [How Stuff Works article](http://entertainment.howstuffworks.com/arts/circus-arts/human-blockhead.htm) goes in detail about where to stick the nail.

Comment: It is a very common stunt. I am not exaggerating when I say I have seen this performed over 50 times. I'm quite over it.

Comment: I remember seeing Jim Rose do it back in 1991 or 1992 and tried it myself. Scarily easy to do. But you have to fight a worrying urge to sneeze, as I don't think that would be good!

Answer (score 2):

Scam School also [demonstrated how to do this](http://revision3.com/scamschool/humanblockhead) a while back.